# how to customize step value and lableThumb into md-slider into Angular2?

Tags: angular, slider, material-design

**what i am trying to achieve**

I am using angular 2 Md-slider in a component. i want create time range picker using MD-slider.

**issue**

problem is step value count on 100 but i want 60. for example 9.60 the value of range picker is 10. but now i got 9.01 to 9.99. after `.` i want max 60. how can i achieve it?

also, i want customize label thumb of slider. it is possible? thanks in advance.

**html code**

```
<md-slider class="example-margin" style="width: 300px;"
                               [disabled]="disabled"
                               [invert]="invert"
                               [max]="max"
                               [min]="min"
                               [step]="step"
                               [thumb-label]="thumbLabel"
                               [tick-interval]="tickInterval"
                               [value]="value"
                               [vertical]="vertical"></md-slider>
```

Comment: i used alternet option [ng2-icon-slider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-ion-range-slider)